# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined 4

Tags: javascript

I'am getting this error when I'am trying to run my code:

on the line 31 : Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var winComb = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]];
var cells = new Array(9);
var playerName = $_POST['player'];
var chtr = $_POST['emotion'];
var uchtr = "";

if(chtr=="xChar"){
    chtr="x";
    uchtr="o";
}
else{
    chtr="o";
    uchtr="x";
}

function player(id){

    win();
    insert(id, "p");
    computer();
}

function computer(){

    var x = 0;

    for(var i=0;i<=winComb.length;i++){

        for(var j=0;j<winComb[i].length;j++){

            if(winComb[i][j]==chtr){

                x++;
            }

            if(x==2){

                for(var k=0;k<winComb[i].length;k++)

                    if(winComb[i][j]==""){

                        insert(winComb[i][j], "c");
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

function shortWinComb(){

    var a = winComb;

    for(var k=1;k<=cells.length;k++){

        if(cells[k]==""){

            for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){

                for(var j=0;i<=a[i].length;i++){

                    if(winComb[i][j]==k){

                        a = a - a[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return a;
}

function win(){

    var x = 0;

    if(!cells==null)

    for(var i=0;i<=shortWinComb().length;i++){

        for(var j=0;i<=shortWinComb()[i].length;i++){

            if(shortWinComb()[i][j]==chtr){

                x++;
            }

            if(x==3){

                for(var k=1;k<=9;k++){

                    lockCell(k);
                }

                alert("*~*~* "+player+" Wins ! *~*~*");
            }

            else if(shortWinComb()[i][j]==uchtr){

                x++;
            }

            if(x==3){

                for(var k=1;k<=9;k++){

                    lockCell(k);
                }

                alert("*~*~* Computer Wins ! *~*~*");
            }
        }

        x = 0;
    }
}

function insert(id, actor){

    var cell = document.getElementById(id);

    if(cell.innerHTML=="")
        if(actor=="p")
            cell.innerHTML = "<img src=images/"+chtr+".png>";
        else
            cell.innerHTML = "<img src=images/"+uchtr+".png>";

    for(var i=1; i<=cells.length;i++){

        if(id==i){
            if(actor=="p")
                cells[i]==chtr;
            else
                cells[i]==uchtr;
            break;
        }
    }

    lockCell(id);
}

function lockCell(id){

    var cell = document.getElementById(id);
    cell.onclick="";
    cell.style.cursor="";
}
</script>
</head>
```

so where is the problem in my code?? I'am newbie to js and I don't know too much about these errors.

Comment: $_POST shouldn't go between php tags?

Comment: $_POST is a variable declared from another js script I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
i<=winComb.length
```

Eventually, that `i` will end up being `winComb.length`, so `winComb[i]` will be undefined. As you probably know, arrays in javascript have items at indexes between `0` and `length-1`.

Fix:

```
i<winComb.length
```

PS: The mistake is repeated in several places. (including one loop where you iterate from 1 to length).

PSS: If you don't have to deal with older browsers (or can use a polyfill for missing functionality) you can use a more functional way of iterating over the elements in an array:

```
arr.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
  /* code inside loop */  
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: thank you, I changed the values of i & j and forgot to change the comparison operators :(